# AutoLayout: UIButton hugs bottom UITabBarItem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, constraints, autolayout

In the lower-left hand corner `UIViewController`s views I have a `UIButton` (`UIButtonTypeInfoDark`). When the app runs on the 4S is looks like you'd expect. But when I run the app on the iPhone 5 it stays where it was instead of "sticking" to the `UITabBarItem` at the bottom.

Is this something that autolayout can handle for me or do I have to programmatically reposition the button? Note: My app is portrait-only so I am not concerned with rotations.

Thanks in advance,
CS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of things.

1. make sure autolayout is on (IB on the "File Inspector Tab")
2. Make sure you are NOT making any changes that involve bounds, frame, etc. - this is all done by Auto constraints now.
3. Make sure you stay away from AutoResizingMask. This will compete with your new settings.

If these are done right, you can now layout your button and it will work great.  Here's how.

1. Drag the mentioned button into the bottom-left corner.
2. You will see guides pop-up when it gets close to the corner on the left hand side, just above your toolbar.
3. Now inspect your constraints by selecting the button and going in the "Size Inspector" tab.
4. Now select the button and the buttonbar.
5. Add new constraint by selecting the graphic that's in the bottom right corner of you mat and pick the middle icon that looks like a capital "I" laying on it's side.
6. Select "Vertical Spacing"
7. You will see a new contraint pop up in the constraints.  Select that new constraint and select "Attribute Inspector"
8. Keep "Relation" to equal and select the checkbox "Standard".  This will keep it the standard height above the buttonbar.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You could work with your autoresizingMask like this:

```
button.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;
```

Comment: Thanks Ismael. I set the `autoresizingMask` on my button but its location remains fixed when I switch between the 4S and 5. Also, did you mean `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin`? I tried that too - same behavior.

Comment: The ~BottomMargin will make it top edge fixed at the same distance from the top, and variate it's bottom margin (the default behavior), as opposed to the ~TopMargin which should make it stick to the bottom.

I'm not entirely familiar with auto layouts, but if you are using them, you need to make sure that the button is configured to stick to the bottom.

Comment: Thanks Ishmael - yeah, this is the first time I'm using AutoLayout and can't seem to figure out how to make the button maintain its distance from the tab bar.

Comment: Reading a little about AutoLayout, I think you should select your button and go `Editor` > `Pin` > `Bottom Space to Superview`

Comment: Nope, that doesn't seem to do it either. If you are bored, to this: create a new `UIViewController` in IB and place a button near the bottom. Use the "Apply Form Factor" button (at the bottom right of the IB work surface) to change form factors and you'll see that the button doesn't move (even if you pin it).

Comment: Ok, trying some other things because my real layout is a little more complicated than I let on.